# Windows 10 2004 error saving passwords

Tags: windows-10, visual-studio-2019, sql-management-studio

after the win10 2004 update I got this behavior:
seems that all the 'Microsoft' programs and some other doesn't' save the user passwords:

- visual studio 2019, every time I open it show me to sign in: I do and the next time I need to resign in;
- SQL server management studio: doesn't save the server password (I checked 'remember password');
- Microsoft office: same behavior of visual studio;
- Google Chrome: each time I launch I need to re do the access (to sync);

any ideas?

thanks!

Comment: Was the 2004 update suggested by Windows Update, or did you force the issue by downloading it? Was this done very recently?

Comment: It was suggested, not forced: it has done about 2 weeks ago...

Comment: It's not too late to rollback the 2004 update (you have 28 days).

Comment: This is a known issue in Windows 10 v2004. [Windows 10 v2004 forgets stored credentials](https://www.winhelponline.com/blog/windows-10-forgets-stored-credentials-passwords-outlook-apps/)